# Converting string to a line of command? c# mac

Tags: c#

So I'm sort of new to C# and I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. I've read on how to do it using CodeDom http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saf5ce06.aspx, but I just can't get anything to work. For example:

```
string toExecute = "Console.WriteLine('Hello world')";
```

//How would I make it so that toExecute is executable. i.e: Execute(toExecute);

output:

Hello world!

---

I've tried this and I keep getting an error(I don't even understand it!):

```
string toExecute = "Console.WriteLine('Hello World')";
Type thisType = this.GetType();
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(toExecute);
theMethod.Invoke(this, null);
```

---

So if someone could give me an example on how to do this one thing and explain it, then I would probably be able to work from there(If it's even possible). 
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are new to C#, I suggest you not to start with _code generation_ and _reflection_. It is not the first things to learn!

Comment: It really will help if you told us why you need to do this; there are many ways of implementing runtime commands, and which way is best for you depends on things you haven't told us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have my visual studio on this computer so haven't run it but I think this should work:

```
object[] parametersArray = new object[] { "Hello" };
MethodInfo writeLine = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] {typeof(string)});
writeLine.Invoke(null, parametersArray)
```

Maybe post what you're trying to accomplish, doing this sort of stuff is a pain in the butt especially if you're newer to .net

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx

Comment: Would it be possible to have: string class1 = "Console"; typeof(class1);, rather than: typeof(Console)?? So the Class would also be in string.

Comment: I ran your code in LinqPad works just fine. It's missing a semi colon so I will update that for you. Sorry also changed the variables to var since it wouldn't just let me do the ; as an edit.

Comment: @user2616745 I don't believe so, you need to reference a concrete class for non-static methods and a concrete type (not a string) for static methods.

Answer (score 0):

CodeDOM is among the easiest ways of doing so. But anyway, it's quite a difficult task, since C# isn't designed to do so. It's one of the fundamental bases of static, compiled languages, all code must be known beforehand, at compile time, since it isn't interpreted on the fly as you would do with a plain string, even if it contains valid code. Really, what matters and gets executed is the bytecode inside the exe/dll.

It's also often not a good idea to try those things, as you completely lose the safety the compiler gives you, and makes your code much harder to debug when problems arise in the dynamically generated code. It's quite an advanced feature, not good for learning if you're new. Things like this are common in other dynamic languages but for C# is quite complex.

BTW, are you trying to accomplish something in particular? Or just asking if it's possible? Probably there are much easier ways of doing the same without resorting to runtime code generation.

Comment: Yes.Yes.Yes. I do need it for what I'm working on :-). Code generation would be based on input and other things. I wouldn't be saving the code, just executing it.

Comment: @user2616745 It's on a different language (JavaScript), but have you ever read one of the articles on "eval is evil"? There's probably a considerable security risk to generating C# code directly based on input.